# insert data in database table from plugin with WP3.1

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, database, wp-query

I am quite new in WP Plugin World. I am trying to develop a plugin in WP 3.1 when I am trying to insert data into my table named "`wp_enam`" in the following way:

```
$wpdb->insert($wpdb->enam, array('username' => "enam" ,
                                 'useremail' => "myemail@somedomain.com"));
```

it is not working.

I try to debug it in following way:

```
$wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->insert($wpdb->enam, array('username' => "enam" ,
                                 'useremail' => "myemail@somedomain.com"));
$wpdb->print_error();
```

Now I am getting following message from MR.WP

```
WordPress database error: [Incorrect table name '']
INSERT INTO `` (`username`,`useremail`) VALUES ('enam','myemail@somedomain.com')

WordPress database error: [Incorrect table name '']
INSERT INTO `` (`username`,`useremail`) VALUES ('enam','myemail@somedomain.com')
```

As you can see the table name is not showing in the mysql query. Is this a correct way to access a table name with `$wpdb->my_table`? **I am using mysql**. Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:**
Looks like `$wpdb->tblname`do not add the table prefix anymore! As per *"Professional WordPress Wrox" by Hal Stern, David Damstra and Brad Williams"* (which is a great book ) it should work. The above functionality is explained at this book in the following way:

```
$wpdb->my_custom_table to reference the table in WordPress. 
This translates to wp_my_custom_table if wp_ is the table prefix. 
This is the proper way to determine the correct table prefix when working with tables in the WordPress database.
```

(*Page:107*)

Comment: Huh. I don't think that ever worked. Probably worth submitting an errata report, although the newer book "Professional WordPress Plugin Development" doesn't repeat that error, so it may have already been caught.

Comment: @goldenapples Thanks for your reply. I will collect the newer one of that book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check database function for database [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb). For the table prefix matter you should use `$wpdb->prefix . 'enam'` and it will return the table prefix. Just add the table name with this. So the total code would be :

```
$yourtablename =  $wpdb->prefix . 'enam';
```

so your total code could be something like:

```
$wpdb->insert($yourtablename , array('username' => "enam" ,
                             'useremail' => "myemail@somedomain.com"));
```

EDIT:
If you need more information you can see [THIS](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) article. This is very useful article for creating plugin with database.

Comment: what is the book name , anyway?

Comment: The book name is: "Professional WordPress Wrox" by Hal Stern, David Damstra and Brad Williams. It is really a nice book, though I just stack into the inserting data into db part(it actually wrote for WP2.8.X, I guess)

Answer (score 3):

You should use something like

```
$wpdb->prefix . 'table_name'
```

instead.

If you don't wan't to repeat your table name through your code save it in a variable or create a function like this one: (nothing cool, but I use it this way, works if you have just one custom table, so it is not very versatile..)

```
function get_table_name() {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->prefix . 'table_name';
}
```

Comment: +1 well, nice idea. Actually, I find '$wpdb->my_table' this in a book which is written for WP2.8.X. Is this not legal in WP3.1?

Comment: I set the table name as a property: `$wpdb->enam = $wpdb->base_prefix . 'enam';`. Now you can use `$wpdb->enam` as you were!

Comment: @TheDeadMedic wOw nice idea. But, do you have any idea why $wpdb->enam is not working in my code for WP3.1? Because, as per that book it should add the table prefix with the table name(as you do here!)?

Comment: Place this as the first line of your plugin's code, and you'll be able to use it anytime after that; `$GLOBALS['wpdb']->enam = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->base_prefix . 'enam';`

Answer (score 0):

I think the wpdb->enam is incorrect, it doesnt exist , you just have to enter tablename there.

```
$wpdb->insert("table_name", array('username' => "enam" ,
                             'useremail' => "myemail@somedomain.com"));
```

Comment: as per http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class $wpdb->tablename is legal....:|

Comment: `$wpdb->tablename` is only valid for tablenames that are registered as properties of the $wpdb class. You can see how the default tables are registered in wp-includes/wp-dp.php - its basically the same way as @TheDeadMedic's answer above.